# Java wont run in firefox?

Tags: firefox, java, browser, plugins

I have Icedtea installed, but when I go to run my favorite Java application, Runescape, in the browser, it says I don't have Java installed in Firefox. Is there any way to say, turn it on?

Comment: Make sure the browser plugin is installed, either `icedtea-6-plugin` or `icedtea-7-plugin`, depending on the java version.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize icedtea was different from the browser plugin. I feel dense.If you could repost that as the answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the browser plugin is installed, either `icedtea-6-plugin` or `icedtea-7-plugin`, depending on the java version you have installed.